# Importing a lot of csv's in MSAccess using a macro

Tags: csv, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a lot of csv files with the name: oilcleared_oil_yyyy_mm_dd.csv". I want to be able to import them into an access table I have called, Sheet1. The table has the following columns.

[image]

I want the user to import the date for the file to be imported, however, as you will see from the csv the first two rwo need to be excluded and the columns in the csv mapped to the table columns.

So far I have the following, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub csv_import()

Dim DATE1 As String
Dim PATH As String

Msg = "Enter Date as dd/mm/yyyy"
    
UserEntry = InputBox(Msg)
If UserEntry = "" Then Exit Sub
If IsDate(UserEntry) Then
DATE1 = Format(UserEntry, "yyyy_mm_dd")
Else
Msg = "Please try again.  Enter date as dd/mm/yyyy"
End If

'DATE1 = Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd")
PATH = "C:\Users\icecleared_oil_" & DATE1 & ".csv"

On Error GoTo Bad
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Import-icecleared_oil", "Sheet1", PATH, True

Exit Sub

Bad:
MsgBox "The File for the date " & DATE1 & " cannot be found in the directory " & PATH & " OR the file 
is currently opened by another user"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do I then ensure that the data goes into the right columns?

Comment: You import to a new table, then copy the data over using a query when finished, and delete the table. Anything else will make it difficult.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try